# Why is PropertyChangedEvent is only firing once for an AttachedProperty

Tags: c#, .net, wpfdatagrid, attached-properties, attachedbehaviors

The OnShouldRefreshPropertyChanged is only firing once and will not fire when the value for NeedsRefresh are changed. Can someone please explain what is going on? The Datagrid i am using is from WPFToolKit for .Net 3.5, though i do not think that matters.

**Behavior:**

```
public static class DataGridRefreshBehavior
{
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ShouldRefresh.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShouldRefreshProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ShouldRefresh",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(DataGridRefreshBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnShouldRefreshPropertyChanged));

    public static void SetShouldRefresh(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        if (obj != null)
            obj.SetValue(ShouldRefreshProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetShouldRefresh(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
            return (bool)obj.GetValue(ShouldRefreshProperty);
        else
            return false;
    }

    private static void OnShouldRefreshPropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var attachedObject = sender as DataGrid;
        if (attachedObject != null)
        {
            bool needsRefresh = (bool)e.NewValue;
            if (needsRefresh)
            {
                attachedObject.Items.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml:**

```
local:DataGridRefreshBehavior.ShouldRefresh="{Binding Path=NeedsRefresh,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public bool NeedsRefresh
    {
        get
        {
            return needsRefresh;
        }
        set
        {

            needsRefresh = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => NeedsRefresh);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it not firing at all or is `e.NewValue` coming back as `false`?. What is `NotiyfOfPropertyChange(...)` doing? You normally have to specify the values to the `DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs`

Comment: In your code, do you ever set/update the `ShouldRefresh` property manually (by calling `SetShouldRefresh()`)? This will break the binding (which is OneWay by default), and further changes to `NeedsRefresh` are ignored. Try setting the binding mode to TwoWay and see if that helps: `..Path=NeedsRefresh, Mode=TwoWay..`.

Comment: It fires the first time, then it doesn't even fire, I am not calling the SetShouldRefresh manually, All i do is call NeedsRefresh = true. NotipfyPropertyChange is similar to OnPropertyChanged("NeedsRefresh")

Comment: You only set `NeedRefresh = true`? You need to alternate between setting it true and false, so the value actually *changes*.

Comment: Well, i was under the impression that if i call OnNotifyPropertyChanged the value will be read irrespective, whether it actually changed or not. Thanks for helping me realize my stupidity, i will go hide in the basement now :)

Comment: No problem. "Helping" people realize their own stupidity is one of my favorite hobbies ;)